# How to check how many shared file users have the file open?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheets file shared with a dozen editors. There's a relatively complex form that can't be run in Forms. I want to ensure in case multiple people have the file open that they don't overwrite each others' form entries.

*Can I trap if more than one person has the file open?* (I could then, for example, disable editing until the first user leaves the file.)

Education counts, but I'd like to avoid asking them to look top-right to see if others have the file open.

Comment: Probably you want this: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Apps Script that may suit your needs to only allow one editor at a time.

```
function getCurrentUserEmail() {
    var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    if (userEmail === '' || !userEmail || userEmail === undefined) {
        userEmail = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty('userEmail');
        if (!userEmail) {
            var protection = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1').protect();
            protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
            var editors = protection.getEditors();
            if (editors.length === 2) {
                var owner = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getOwner();
                editors.splice(editors.indexOf(owner), 1);
            }
            userEmail = editors[0];
            protection.remove();
            PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty('userEmail', userEmail);
        }
    }
    return userEmail;
}
```